# Alternative for oncontextmenu - javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml, contextmenu

I'm looking for a JavaScript alternative to `onContextMenu` in an xHTML page. I want to hide the menu which pops-up (The context menu) When I click the right mouse button on a website.

I have a problem using the `onContextMenu` attribute because it doesn't pass the validator for xHTML Strict.

Comment: What's wrong with onContextMenu?

Comment: It is not xHTML strict.

Comment: Does anyone use xHTML?  I thought this was deprecated

Comment: Then use html5, or attach event handlers instead of using html attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond and all, but you are being quite useless so far. The point is I -have- to use xHTML Strict and my code has to fully pass the validator. If it was a matter of just changing the doctype I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Add it via `addEventHandler`, bypassing the attribute-style

Comment: @PitaJ You should phrase that advice into an answer, treating cases like IE.old (using attachEvent). It's a perfectly acceptable strategy for dealing with OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you attach to `oncontextmenu` in an external script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

(Make sure you include the `type` attribute, so it validates.)

**`script.js`:**

```
document.body.oncontextmenu = function handleContextMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: This method is almost universally decried. In fact, it may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Which part of it?  Why?  Where?

Comment: Assigning an event listener using `addEventListener(eventType, func)` if much preferred to using the `onEventType` property of the DOM element.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  The fundamentals of the solution are the same - it's just a syntactical change.  `onEventType` here is a simple demonstration of the overall point, without the need to check and implement the variations on `addEventListener` for different browsers.